# Amazon SES emails not delivering to Outlook and hotmail based ids

Tags: outlook, nodemailer, amazon-ses

I am using Amazon SES to send transnational updates,using nodemailer to create transport. Emails are not delivering to outlook or hotmail based emails, gmail, yahoo and other services are working fine. To make sure there is no issue in I have checked code with gmail based smtp setting, it is working fine(emails are getting delivered to outlook). But Amazon SES based ones are not sending. SPF,DKIM records are configured properly by our devops. Even test mail in AWS console is also not working with outlook/hotmail based ids.
Any insights would be welcome.

Comment: did you find any solution to this? I am facing same problem.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things I found out.
One if the ip is blacklisted by hotmail or microsoft based email service. we can send request here
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/supportrequestform/8ad563e3-288e-2a61-8122-3ba03d6b8d75

If it is not delivering to office 365 user we can directly delist by using this link.
https://sender.office.com/